# How to use external media in virtualbox windows installation

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit

I have Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit and I have Windows 7 Professional installed in virtualbox. I want to be able to plug my ipod in and use itunes from the Windows installation. I can't install Windows 7 of my PC because when it boots for the first time the screen goes black for hours. My only other option is virtualbox, when I go to Orical's website it only has downloads for Ubuntu 13.04, What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [Oracle Virtualbox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)  both 13.04 and 13.10 are on the same line at the very top. It says

> Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring Ringtail") / 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander")

Click on the AMD64 link next to that to get the 13.10 64 bit version. Make sure you download the extension pack as well so that you will have the USB support as well. When you install Windows in VB, make sure you install the Guest Additions as well.